# CodeIgniter - session record not deleted from database (CI - 2.1.4)

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have set my config to make the session expire on close, and have used the database table provided in the CI manual to store the sessions.

But when I close my browser, the session data is still stored in the database. What I'm worried about is session hijacking; the record remains in the database (i.e. userdata: loggedin == true) and the user can just set their own session with that value and off they go.

Why isn't the record in the database being deleted on browser close, when the user doesn't click the logout button, but instead closes their browser window?

my config settings:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cisess';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'usersess';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Answer (score 0):

Session hijacking is pretty unlikely. Someone would need access to your database (which relies on you to secure it), also would need the same user agent and spoof the IP. Not to mention they'd need an exact copy of the user cookie as well which requires access to the users browser on their computer.

Also you set the sess_expiration to 0 which means it never expires. Set it to 1  and see how it performs.

EDIT: Never mind setting it to one would let the user login and then it would be expired. Apologies for that. Try setting it to a lower time limit though, maybe around 30-40 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried setting sess_expiration to a value other than 0, it does delete the userdata column (but not the entire row). But the underlying problem is still there really i.e. not doing this when the user closes their browser

Comment: I'm going to give this custom session class a try: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/PK-Session and see how it goes. Seems like others have had the same issue. Gotta love open source :)

Comment: I think entire row is not deleted from session table even-though we destroy session. A new session id (row) is created every time we login but it is not deleted from table. Does ci check id each time to create new id.